# How to find shading in Word document using color number from WordOpenXML

Tags: vba, colors, ms-word

I have to change every shading `BackgroundPatternColor` to `Highlight` (don't ask "why?", I have to)
Changing character by character is very, very slow.
Fastest way is using `.Find` method.

But in documents can be a lot of different shading colors (24-bit color).
In WordOpenXML is sth. like this:

```
  <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="8064A2">
```

From this xml, I know that "8064A2" shading color was used in document - that "8064A4" number is hex RRGGBB mask , and its mean `RGB(128, 100, 162)` - hex "80" is 128 decimal etc.

But... function `RGB(128, 100, 162)` return 10642560.
The shading I'm looking for return -687800321

```
Debug.print Selection.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
```

Why? and how to receive -687800321 number from RGB (because `Selection.Find.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -687800321` works great)

Comment: Sounds like you have a cool boss :-P  So... rather than search for all the possible colors can you search for shading that has  NOT no_color  (e.g. some color) and convert to highlight?

Comment: I thought about it, but it is very slow too. Especially if there is no shading in doc.
I have couple thousands large docs to review (every week) therefore I'm looking for extremally fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this article explains what is going on: http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007BuildSet.php

In a nutshell you are dealing with Theme Colors and the reason they don't seem to convert from Hex to RGB is because they are modified by a 'lightness-darkness' accent.

The article describes how the color system works - as far as I can tell, as you found out, the number you are looking for: -687800321 when written in HEX is: &HD**7**00FFFF *(which is NOT RGB)*; instead this notation represents theme color "number 7" with lightness-darkness of FFFF.

I think this essentially means you will need to create / find some sort of translation table to store in your conversion macro (or figure out what all the theme colors are and do something sneaky, see below).

---

Gah, annoyingly, I have just realised it gets worse - read here:
http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php

Anyway there is a solution based on the understanding that MS Word stores the RGB but insists on using the theme information to find the shading. So for a simple 2 word document you have:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="C0504D" w:themeFill="accent2"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Red</w:t>
</w:r>
...
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="E5B8B7" w:themeFill="accent2" w:themeFillTint="66"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Red-Lighter</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Both the fill values (C0504D) & (E5B8B7) are RGB but you have to use the Theme information for find and replace which is annoying... So, for example, you have to use `w:themeFill="accent2"` & `w:themeFillTint="66"`.

And then you can use this function (see below) from the original article to convert accent**2** and tint**66** into the obscure number that are otherwise unable to determine.

```
' All Credit to Tony Jollans - http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php
Function GetThemeColor(ThemeColorIndex As WdThemeColorIndex, TintAndShade As Double) As Long

    Const HexadecimalPrefix As String = "&H"
    Const UseThemeColor     As String = "D"
    Const UnusedZeroByte    As String = "00"
    Const Unchanged         As String = "FF"

    Dim ThemeColor          As String
    Dim LightnessOrDarkness As String

    ThemeColor = Hex$(ThemeColorIndex)

    If TintAndShade >= 0 Then
        LightnessOrDarkness = Unchanged & Right$("0" & Hex$((1 - TintAndShade) * &HFF), 2)
    Else
        LightnessOrDarkness = Right$("0" & Hex$((1 + TintAndShade) * &HFF), 2) & Unchanged
    End If

    GetThemeColor = CLng(HexadecimalPrefix & UseThemeColor & ThemeColor & UnusedZeroByte & LightnessOrDarkness)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After long investigation I've almost* find a solution. Here is my second topic in other forum.
https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/2ea570b5-ce3a-4f37-a37c-9b2100941d39/how-to-find-shading-in-word-document-using-color-number-reciving-from-wordopenxml

All magic is in bits :)

```
part 1  part 2       part 3        part 4            part 5
fixed   w:themeFill  don't know    w:themeFillShade  w:themeFillTint
1101    0111         00000000      11111111          11111111
```

part 1.
Fixed for theme colors (negative number)

part 2.
w:themeFill is WdThemeColorIndex Enumeration (accent4 == 7 == 0111)

part 3.
Still looking what's this

part 4.
w:themeFillShade==11111111 ("FF") if ommited in xml

part 5.
w:themeFillTint==11111111 ("FF") if ommited in xml

w:fill has no influence to color number if w:themeFill is used.

---

*almost, because 9-16bits are still mystery.